# Android - calling startIntentSenderForResult from a service

Tags: android, authentication, mobile, google-plus, intentservice

I have created an Auth IntentService that handles Google+ sign in, I would like to prompt for user sign in if the connectionResult has resolution.

```
//...
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_AUTH)) {
        doAuth(new AuthCallback() {
            @Override
            public void authed(String token) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_AUTHED);
                intent.putExtra("token", token);
                localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

protected void doAuth(AuthCallback callback) {
    Log.d("GoogleAuthIntentService", "Google Auth");

    //doing login, getting token
    mConnectionResult = mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect();
    if (mConnectionResult.isSuccess()) {
        //return the user data (not yet implemented)
        callback.authed("USER DATA");
    } else if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        // prompt to sign in
        // How can I call startIntentSenderForResult ???
    }

}
```

When I get to the point where I want to resolve the sign in, I have no startIntentSenderForResult method.

What would be the right approach in order to **keep the sign in logic in the service**?